# como se puede comparar un vector en una matriz en java para que luego se me sume en un contador

Tags: java, array

La cuestión como tal es que a la hora de imprimir la cantidad de aciertos me aparece en 0 aunque el vector tiene los mismos valores que la matriz.

```
//Estos son mis vectores y matrices globales
int cargar[];
int boleto[];
int sorteo[][];
int num;

public Balotomatriz() {
    num = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite eltamaño de las filas: "));
    sorteo = new int[num][5];
    boleto = new int[5];
    cargar = new int[num];
}

//Aqui es donde no me imprime lo que quiero
    public void aciertos() {
        int acierto = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sorteo.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                cargar[acierto] = sorteo[i][j];
                if (cargar[acierto] == boleto[j]) {
                    acierto++;
                }
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El numero de aciertos es de: " + acierto + "\n");
    }
public void llenar() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int num1;
        for (int i = 0; i < sorteo.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                num1 = random.nextInt(49) + 1;
                sorteo[i][j] = num1;
            }
        }

    }

    public void mostrarllenar() {
        String acu = " ";
        String acu1 = " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < sorteo.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                acu = acu + "| " + sorteo[i][j] + " |";
            }

            acu = acu + "\n";

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            acu1 = acu1 + "| " + boleto[i] + " |";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Boleto generado es: \n" + acu1 + "\n Serial personal: \n" + acu );
    }

    public void boletoganador() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int num1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            num1 = random.nextInt(49) + 1;
            boleto[i] = num1;

        }
    }
```

Comment: El problema en si esta en como se puede hacer la comparacion entre un vector de tamaño 5 donde me guarda valores random con una matriz de n*5 con valores random tambien

Comment: ¿Puedes subir todo el código?

Comment: si claro sin ningun problema

Comment: El código tiene varios problemas en los métodos. Pero para comprenderlo mejor, necesito saber que es lo que quieres hacer en el ejercicio. Un enunciado o algo...

Comment: El ejercicio  es un baloto donde se tiene que ingresar 5 números del 1 al 49 en una matriz de n filas por 5 columnas y en un vector de tamaño 5 donde me guardará el boleto ganador, lo que me piden es que coja ese vector y lo compare con la matriz y mirar si hay números iguales para luego guardarlo en el contador aciertos por cada número correcto.